# VHDL signal does not change value

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I am currently trying to implement a state machine with 5 different states. Basically, I want to stay in one state, wait for some time, move on to the next state, wait for a different amount of time, get into the next state etc....

For now I implemented a counter which generates a 1s signal from a 1ms signal that I create in the testbench. I created one process that determines the next state and one that upgrades the current state from the next state. The signal which does not behave as I expected is: next_stateHS which should upgrade stateHS. The code in question is in the process called "hsNextState". What I also can't explain is that the signal "startCounter" behaves as expected. This signal receives a new value in the same else - case as the signal "next_StateHS"
I will now add the code for the state machine and the test bench and a picture of the simulated waveform.
State machine:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity ampel is
    port 
    (
        clk : in std_ulogic;
        reset : in std_ulogic;
        enable : in std_ulogic;

        haupt : out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
        neben : out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0)
    );
end ampel;


architecture ampel_behave of ampel is

--Codierung

-- idle     = 000
-- gruen    = 001
-- gelb     = 010
-- rot      = 011
-- rot_gelb = 100


    signal stateHS, stateNS :   std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal next_stateHS, next_stateNS   :   std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    signal startCounter : std_ulogic := '0';

    signal counter  :   unsigned(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');    --für clk = 1ms im Testbench
    signal count_seconds    :   unsigned(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');


begin
    counterProcess : process(clk, reset, enable, startCounter)
    begin
        if enable = '0' or reset = '1' or startCounter = '0' then
            counter <= (others => '0');
            count_seconds <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if counter < "1111101000" then
                counter <= counter + 1;
            else 
                counter <= (others => '0');
                count_seconds <= count_seconds + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process counterProcess; 

    outputProcessHS : process(stateHS, reset, enable)
    begin
        if enable = '0' or reset = '1' then
            haupt   <= "000";
        else
            case (stateHS) is
                when "000" =>
                    haupt   <= "000";
                when "001" =>
                    haupt   <= "001";
                when "010" =>
                    haupt   <= "010";
                when "011" =>
                    haupt   <= "011";
                when "100" =>
                    haupt   <= "100";
                when others =>
                    haupt   <= "000";
            end case;
        end if;
    end process outputProcessHS;

    outputProcessNS : process(stateNS, reset, enable)
    begin
        if enable = '0' or reset = '1' then
            neben   <= "000";
        else
            case (stateNS) is
                when "000" =>
                    neben   <= "000";
                when "001" =>
                    neben   <= "001";
                when "010" =>
                    neben   <= "010";
                when "011" =>
                    neben   <= "011";
                when "100" =>
                    neben   <= "100";
                when others =>
                    neben   <= "000";
            end case;
        end if;

    end process outputProcessNS;

    hsNextState : process(reset, enable, stateHS, count_seconds)
    begin
        if enable = '0' or reset = '1' then
            next_stateHS    <= "000";
        else
            case (stateHS) is
                when "000" =>
                    next_stateHS <= "001";
                    startCounter <= '1';
                when "001" =>
                    if count_seconds < "1110" then
                        next_stateHS <= "001";
                    else
                        next_stateHS <= "010";
                        startCounter <= '0';
                    end if;
                when "010" =>
                    next_stateHS <= "011";

                when "011" =>
                    next_stateHS <= "100";

                when "100" =>
                    next_stateHS <= "001";
                when others =>
                    next_stateHS <= "000";
            end case;
        end if;
    end process hsNextState;

    hsState : process(reset, enable, next_stateHS, count_seconds)
    begin
        if enable = '0' or reset = '1' then
            stateHS <= "000";
        else
            stateHS <= next_stateHS;
        end if;
    end process hsState;


    -- nsStateProcess : process(reset, enable, stateNS, count_seconds)
    -- begin    
        -- if enable = '0' or reset = '1' then
            -- next_stateNS <= idle;
        -- else
            -- case (stateNS) is
                -- when idle =>
                    -- next_stateNS <= gruen;
                -- when gruen =>
                    -- next_stateNS <= gelb;

                -- when gelb =>
                    -- next_stateNS <= rot;

                -- when rot =>
                    -- next_stateNS <= rot_gelb;

                -- when rot_gelb =>
                    -- next_stateNS <= gruen;

                -- when others =>
                    -- next_stateNS <= idle;
            -- end case;    
        -- end if;
        -- stateNS <= next_stateNS;
    -- end process nsStateProcess;

end ampel_behave;
```

Test Bench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity ampel_tb is
end ampel_tb;

architecture test of ampel_tb is
    component ampel
        port 
        (
            clk : in std_ulogic;
            reset : in std_ulogic;
            enable : in std_ulogic;

            haupt : out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
            neben : out std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    signal clk : std_ulogic := '0';
    signal reset : std_ulogic := '0';
    signal enable : std_ulogic := '1';
    signal haupt, neben : std_ulogic_vector(2 downto 0);
    signal count_cycles : unsigned (19 downto 0) := (others => '0');

begin
    ampel_1 : ampel port map
        (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            enable => enable,
            haupt => haupt,
            neben => neben
        );

    clock_signal : process
    begin
        if count_cycles < "0011100000000000000" then
            clk <= '0';
            wait for 500 us;
            clk <= '1';
            wait for 500 us;
            count_cycles <= count_cycles + 1;
        else
            wait;
        end if;
    end process clock_signal;
end test;
```

[image: Simulation]

Comment: `The signal which does not behave as I expected is: next_stateHS which should upgrade stateHS.` [next_stateHS is doing exactly what your design specification directs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnWnj.jpg)

Comment: Both process `hsNextState` and process `hsState` are combinational (not clocked) and form an asynchronous state machine.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks for your reply. I still don't understand, why "next_stateHS" never becomes "010".

Comment: @rtx13 I thought making only the counter dependable on the clock would be sufficient because the process of changing the states depends on the counter and therefore indirectly on the clock itself.

Comment: @Alex in a synchronous state machine (if that's what you intend), the `state` is a registered signal, in other words it is an explicitly clocked assignment.  As written, you have a mostly asynchronous state machine partly driven by a synchronous input.